# Error while trying to execute an activity from different package

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 2 packages :

1)com.example.appui

2)com.example.mapsApi

I want to start the main activity of the second package from the first one. Here is my code :

On the manifest  `<activity android:name="com.example.mapsApi.MapsActivity"/>`

On the activity :

```
 try{
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setClassName("com.example.mapsApi","com.example.mapsApi.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
}catch (Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The error i got is :
Unable to find explicit class (com.example.mapsApi.MapsActivity) have declared it in the manifest?

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: have you tried it as `Intent intent = new Intent();` by creating Intent without Action ?

Comment: I just tried it,i had the same exception

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but do you have an app that has the com.example.mapsApi.MapsActivity on your phone/Simulator

Comment: No i don't have any app like this on the phone

Comment: Entreco has a point : to start the mapsApi app, you need the actually install it first ...

Comment: Install what? i have the 2 packages on the same apk

Answer (score 0):

You can leave the full path in the manifest file.
in your code try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
```

and make an import of this activity at the top of the java class with the full path like this:

```
import com.example.mapsApi.MapsActivity;
```

Comment: That's what i did in the first place and i had a NoClassDefFoundError exception

Comment: Yes   <activity android:name="com.example.mapsApi.MapsActivity"/>

Comment: try to use lower case only in your package name.

Comment: it was already maps but when i had this exception, i tried to change it to mapsApi

Comment: @EmilAdz : "different package" probably indicates different apks